# Alternative of withNavigationFocus from @react-navigation/native in react navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

Is there any alternate to `withNavigationFocus` imported from `@react-navigation/native`? or can we write our own `withNavigationFocus` just like we can write our own `withNavigation` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63818841/14341861.